# assign image to annotation instead of pin

Tags: ios, swift3, mkpinannotationview

Hi Guys I am trying to replace the pin on my annotation to a custom image.

I already have the images in my image.cassette list will displays 1X 2X 3X etc. but as soon as I try to call that image I get an error in my code where `Xcode` tries to fix my syntax but eventually throws it out as error

my code listed below override func

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
        return nil
    }


    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView =   mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {

        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "House")
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Now `Xcode` is picking up an error here in code annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "House") where it ask to insert ","  and the end result looks like this

```
annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "#imageLiteral(resourceName: ",House,")")
```

`Xcode` will then display an error  use of unresolved identifier 'House'

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: use of unresolved identifier 'House'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 3 introduces Image Literals. Just write "Imag".. and it opens popup with Image Literal option. like below image:

[image]

By selecting "Image Literal" option, It will popup all available assets images,

[image]

Select image you want to use from the grid.

for more details, [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIeKF.gif)

Answer (score 0):

this code helped me fixed my issue

```
let pinImage = UIImage(named: "House.png")
annotationView.image = pinImage
```

but i now have a issue where my map is not centered anymore